# Rails 4: Using acts_as_taggable_on to link two models which have common tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, acts-as-taggable-on

I have 2 models. A user model and a micropost model. Both of these models are taggable.

User.rb

```
 acts_as_taggable
 acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```

Micropost.rb

```
 acts_as_taggable
 acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```

The tags are enforced from a common list of 30 different "topics".

I am trying to find questions related to a users tags i.e. microposts that the user might be interested in.

Obviously to find users with common tags you can

```
   @users = @user.find_related_tags
```

But how can you do this across 2 models.

I have tried something stupid like

```
 micropost = Micropost.new
 micropost.tag_list = current_user.tag_list
 @questions_list = micropost.find_related_tags
```

Where I hoped @questions_list would be an array of related microposts.This doesn't work

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like

```
Micropost.tagged_with(@user.tag_list, :on => :tags, :any => true)
```

Based on [this section from the docs](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#relationships).

Comment: Ah drats. I tried this but my version was not quite correct. You sir, have saved me a lot. Many thanks.....!

Comment: I have a model `Product` which `has_many :taxons, through: :classifications`. How to implement `acts_as_taggable_on` to implement the tagging of profucts with the names of taxons?